# Тернарник внутри блока if - порядок операций C#

Tags: c#, if, тернарный-оператор, приоритет

Не могу понять порядок выполнения операций в следующем коде

```cs
var a = true;
var b = true;
var c = true;

if (a == true
    || b == true
    || c ? false : true)
{
    // Сюда не попадаем
    var q = 10;
    Console.WriteLine(q);
}
```

Если завернуть тернарник в скобки `(c ? false : true)`, то тогда попадаем внутрь блока if. Разве тернарный оператор не считается за единую операцию? И если он таким не является, то всё равно не укладывается в голове почему игнорируются остальные сравнения?

Comment: Вопрос конечно хороший, но на код-ревью за такое бьют, лучше не стоит использовать подобный синтаксис из-за нечитабельности, хотя конечно вкусовщина очень)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Условный тернарный оператор имеет [почти самый низкий приоритет](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/), поэтому сначала выполняется логическое ИЛИ, а потом уже результат используется в тернарнике, примерно так:

```
if ( (a == true || b == true  || c)
                                 ? false : true)
```

Скобки вокруг тернарного оператора помогают реализовать именно ту логику, которую вы хотите.

P.S. `a == true` не надо писать, достаточно просто использовать `a`